# github show commits on a specific date

Tags: github

I can show/search a list of commits on a specific branch on github like this

> https://github.com/username/repository/commits/branch_name

I can also filter by author name like

> https://github.com/username/repository/commits/branch_name?author=author_name

But I am looking for a way that I can search my commits on a specific date or date range. I tried to find an existing answer but could not find. I also tried some queries like `before=2016-07-27` or `after=2016-07-27` but it did not work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The compare view might help: https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/master@%7B2015-02-27%7D...master@%7B2015-03-01%7D

Comment: @C-Otto Thank you.. I've seen this here https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/ but it did not help

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Per GitHub's REST API v3 documentation for [list commits on a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

includes `since` and `until` parameters:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name   |  Type   |                          Description                          |
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| since  | string  | Only commits after this date will be returned.                |
|        |         | This is a timestamp in ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ. |
| until  | string  | Only commits before this date will be returned.               |
|        |         | This is a timestamp in ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ. |
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For example, to select commits on master in June 2018 on github/linguist: https://github.com/github/linguist/commits/master?since=2018-05-31&until=2018-07-01

According to the above-linked docs, the branch should be included as a query parameter, e.g. https://github.com/github/linguist/commits?branch=master&since=2018-05-31&until=2018-07-01 but it seems to work fine to use the branch name as a path parameter.

Comment: Thanks @eddies It's been long time but it will help other people, I tested and it worked. Thanks again :)

Comment: Cool. Using `?since=2020-10-01&until=2020-11-01` (as in https://github.com/near/nearcore/commits/master?since=2020-10-01&until=2020-11-01) was helpful in finding a historical commit related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64554355/470749

Comment: Can also tack on `&author=githubUsername` to filter by username

eg https://github.com/github/linguist/commits/master?since=2018-05-31&until=2018-07-01&author=lildude

Answer (score 5):

For public or GitHub Pro repositories, when you click on Network (the number next to fork) you can at least browse by date.

For easier navigation use the cursor keys (shift left for the first commit). Click on a bullet to go to that commit.