# How do I view the original account structure created at genesis of NEAR Protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

Obviously the accounts have changed significantly but is there an easy way to view the mapping of original accounts and balances when the network launched?
Basically, where is the genesis hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the mainnet_genesis.json file: https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/735e6238b702fe59c3cefe1d8e059bce6997acfd/neard/res/mainnet_genesis.json#L248-L341

Search for `"Account"` instances in the file.

Comment: That link is outdated. Try: https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/735e6238b702fe59c3cefe1d8e059bce6997acfd/neard/res/mainnet_genesis.json#L248-L341

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the link in my answer